# How to store variables as unsigned 1024 bit integers and a function to add them in python

Tags: python

I know that the maximum size of integers modern machines can accommodate is
limited to 64 bits in unsigned long form. I need to implement a method that can add two 1024 bit unsigned
big integer numbers. Tried to construct an abstract data type (ADT) in the form of a class named MyBigInteger. Then addition method
def add (a: MyBigInteger, b: MyBigInteger)
How about integer arrays to accommodate several 64 bit long integers to compose the big integer.

Would appreciate some help //novice here!

Comment: As far as I know Python can already do this for you out of the box. Python integers are not like C/C++ ints with a fixed number of bits, instead they're implemented more or less like the big integers you're trying to implement.

Comment: Python `int` is an abstraction around what amounts to a linked list of base-2**30 (or something) digits. You don't have to worry about bit sizes explicitly, as Python doesn't have a type that corresponds directly to multibyte machine words on any particular platform.

Answer (score 0):

As @Joanis said, Python integers may have infinite-size.
For example:

```
  (1<<1024).bit_length() returns 1025  
  (1<<1023)*2 == (1<<1024) returns True  
  (1<<1024) / 1000 returns 1.797693134862316e+305  
  (1<<1024) returns 'OverflowError: int too large to convert to float'
```

You can do arithmetic operation with these large integers.
You can also do bitwise arithmetic with |&~ (or, and, xor).